# api.targets is not a function in plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread

Tags: babeljs

I have this error when I try to compile my app. The error comes from `babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` here https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/6e551ae8827d064680c1344074db9fb3093967e9/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/src/index.js#L22 :

> Trace: error TypeError: api.targets is not a function
> |     at /home/username/Documents/front-newlook/node_modules/next/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js:38:25
> |     at /home/username/Documents/front-newlook/node_modules/next/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/lib/index.js:19:12
> |     at /home/username/Documents/front-newlook/node_modules/next/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:166:14
> |     at cachedFunction (/home/username/Documents/front-newlook/node_modules/next/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/caching.js:32:19)
> |     at loadPluginDescriptor (/home/username/Documents/front-newlook/node_modules/next/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:201:28)
> |     at /home/username/Documents/front-newlook/node_modules/next/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/full.js:71:20

My `babel.config.json` is like this:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "emotion",
    "macros",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["require-context-hook"]
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea? Thank you

Answer (score 9):

The problem was solved when I removed the `node_modules` folder and then ran `yarn install`

Comment: Hate it when this is the answer. Guess node_modules gets corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Run "npm install" once, It will fix the issue.